# How do you print a PKCS10CertificationRequest as a String?

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Is there a way to print the CSR generated with PKCS10CertificationRequest class? I am struggling to see the generated request.

```
PKCS10CertificationRequest certRequest = new PKCS10CertificationRequest(fromByteArray);
System.out.println("CSR string   = "+certRequest.toString()); 
   
System.out.println("CSR Subject Name  = "+certRequest.getSubject().toString());
System.out.println("CSR Subject PubkeyInfo  = "+certRequest.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo().toString());
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hope this can help:

```
PemObject pemObject = new PemObject("CERTIFICATE REQUEST", certRequest.getEncoded());
StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(str);
pemWriter.writeObject(pemObject);
pemWriter.close();
str.close();
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Just a comment for users of older BouncyCastle. There is no PemObject, so pass the CSR directly to pemWriter#writeObject

Comment: `PEMWriter` is depricated. So, Use `JcaPEMWriter` instead.